# Filter data on related object in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have next `ModelSerializers`.

I need the `statistics` data display at 6 days range by default (see `date` field in `StatisticSerializer`). User can to change this date range (from `frontend` get two parameters: `start_date` and `end_date`, which not is in `Models` and `Serializers`.
How can I make this functional?

**serializers**

```
class StatisticSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Statistic
        fields = ['date', 'clicks', 'page_views']


class UserStatisticSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    statistics = StatisticSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'ip_address', 'statistics',
        ]
```

**views**

```
class UserStatisticApiView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserStatisticSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

Comment: Are users supposed to see all users' statistics or just their own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use SerializerMethodField(), docs [enter link description here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

there just some Pseudocode

```
class StatisticSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Statistic
        fields = ['date', 'clicks', 'page_views']


class UserStatisticSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    filtered_statistc = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'ip_address', 'filtered_statistc',
        ]

    def get_filtered_statistc(self,obj):
        result = Statistic.objects.filter('filter there by your params')
        serialized_result = StatisticSerializer(data=result, many=True)
        return serialized_result
```